# Большой /var/lib/mysql/ibdata1

Tags: mysql, файлы, сервер

Я сохранял данные из таблиц в текстовые файлы. Всего вышло примерно 40-60 кбт. Но все файлы mySql занимают 760 мб.

В процессе разработки в таблицы бд вставлялись данные, а также данные обновлялись и удалялись.

Жаль я точно не помню сколько занимал mySql (то есть директория где размещены файлы бд) сразу же после установки. Но было гораздо меньше чем 700 мб.

Сейчас моя бд "занимает" 300 с чем-то кбт, ну то есть это frm файлы заполненные нулями.

```
  du -hs /var/lib/mysql/*

  0       /var/lib/mysql/debian-5.5.flag
  763M    /var/lib/mysql/ibdata1
  5,0M    /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0
  5,0M    /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile1
  316K    /var/lib/mysql/mbs
  1,1M    /var/lib/mysql/mysql
  4,0K    /var/lib/mysql/mysql_upgrade_info
  212K    /var/lib/mysql/performance_schema
```

Как нормализовать (уменьшить, дефрагентировать(?)) файлы бд?

И почему оно так распухло?

Где-то когда-то читал, что это так потому что mySql типа резервирует место для данных - не помню :(.

Таблицы в InnoDB, сервер 5.5.54. Сначала таблицы были в MyISAM.

Comment: а какая версия MySql? какой тип таблиц используется?

Comment: Таблицы в InnoDB, сервер 5.5.54.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Мануал](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html)

> Because the **system tablespace never shrinks**, and is shared across all databases in an instance, avoid loading huge amounts of temporary data on a space-constrained system when *innodb_file_per_tabl*e is disabled. Set up a separate instance in such cases, so that you can drop the entire instance to reclaim the space.

Резюме: Сделать дамп всех БД (либо временно сменить движок - например, на MyISAM), переинициализировать системное хранилище, восстановить БД.

Рекомендация: Включить innodb_file_per_table.

Comment: :( "всей манны сразу не скушаешь". "Рекомендация: Включить innodb_file_per_table." - по названию пвраметра догадывюсь что будет не один большой файл, а по 1 на каждую таблицу.

Comment: Именно. И при этом хранилище каждой отдельно взятой таблицы очень даже нормальненько шринкается. Причём без дополнительных телодвижений.